# C# call dynamic method error

Tags: c#, dynamic

This works :

```
dynamic exp = new List<int>();
exp.Add(4);
```

but this does not:

```
dynamic exp = new List<int>();
exp.Add((object)4);

RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>.Add(int)' has some invalid arguments
```

This is an example, but in the real code I do not know the type but at run time.

Is there a way to make the binder bind with the instance argument types? and only if they don't match raise the exception?

Comment: exp.Add((dynamic)4);

Comment: why are you declaring the List<int> as dynamic? did you mean to use var?

Comment: @Gusman  do not know why I didn't think of that -_-, thanks!

Comment: @Richard I'm working with IDictionay & IDicionary<,> objects and since IDicionary<,> does not Implement IDicionary I need to do the Add with dynamic

Comment: I'm getting a copy & paste comment smell...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that a `List<int>` is *not* a dynamic object. It has a known runtime type and holds `int`.  Declaring the variable as `dynamic` doesn't change that.  You can only add `int` values to that list, otherwise you'd get an exception at runtime.  In your particular case, `List<int>.Add(object)` does not exist and therefore fails with the binder exception.

Since you don't know the type at compile time, rather than making the variable `dynamic`, declare it `IList` instead.  Generic lists implement the `IList` interface which contains `IList.Add(object)` and can accept any type allowed by the underlying implementation (an `int`).  You still need to make sure that the values are compatible with that list however, otherwise you'll get an argument exception.